# How to make azure function to run continuously as it gets stopped after 5 to 6 mins?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-functions

```
public static void Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("SimpleProducer");
    KafkaOptions options = new KafkaOptions(new Uri("http://*******:9092"));
    BrokerRouter router = new BrokerRouter(options);
    Producer client = new Producer(router);
    while(true)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(new
              {
                ExchangeName = "BitFinex",
                CurrencyPair = "Dollar",
                MachineTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss.ffffff"),
                OrderSide = "Buy",
                OrderId = "123",
                Price = "10",
                Quantity = "100"
              });
        log.Info(obj.ToString(Formatting.None));
        client.SendMessageAsync("tenant", new[] { new Message(obj.ToString(Formatting.None)) }).Wait();

        log.Info("Next Iteration");
    }

}
```

I used while loop to process data continuously in azure azure function.But the azure function gets stopped after 5 to 6 mins and I once again have to rerun the azure function. Is there any settings to run azure functions continuously?.I have used the above code.

Comment: Azure Functions are primarily event-driven which means that you need something to trigger the Function (timer, queue, storage etc). Consequently, this makes Functions inappropriate for what you're trying to achieve. WebJobs is better fitted to this task as per the answer below

Answer (score 4):

No, you should use WebJobs for that. Azure Functions are capped at 5 minutes of runtime.

Here's the article to get you started on WebJobs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs

They (Functions and WebJobs) are basically the same thing (made from the same SDK), so porting the code would be trivial.

Answer (score 3):

You may use Azure Functions to execute long running jobs by creating them under the **[App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale)** with **AlwaysOn** enabled.  This option gives you dedicated infrastructure that is always running and will not have the current 5-minute execution time limit.

Comment: I'll add that in the next release of Azure Functions (in the next week or so) we'll be increasing the max timeout value allowed to 10 minutes. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/pull/1502

Comment: I am having the same issue. If I use Functions premium plan will my code keep on running? How do I ensure it runs forever?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75527763/deploying-python-script-in-azure

Comment: Hello @AbhishekRai, yes, if you want your code to keep running beyond the default timeout period for Consumption Plan, then you have to upgrade to the Premium Plan. When using the Premium Plan, your Function will be guaranteed to be running on a minimum of 1 instance.

Comment: @LingToh Hey! Thanks for your response. I am infact using App service plan with "Always On" checked. Looks it will keep it running. Only bummer is I cannot see any output of my print statements from python. It is a 1200 line code. Not sure, How to debug.. :(

Comment: @AbhishekRai, consider using the built-in logging pipeline through Applications Insights as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#logging. 

You can then view your logs in the Monitor Tab. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#view-telemetry-in-monitor-tab

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned before
- create the function in a dedicated Service Plan and not as a "consumption/pay as you go".
Important related information:
- check durable functions that will allow you to have your funcion in singleton and flexible intervals, and the "monitor pattern"
- on durable functions, check eternal orchestrator
- you can also mark your function to be started/triggered manually

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to take the Azure Function approach you better use [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-kafka-extension) custom binding/trigger for Kafka