# Deploying python script in Azure

Tags: python, azure

I have a python script which is making around 10,000 API calls, and sending the data from these calls to an SQL DB. It also needs to read/write from 2 text files and this programme needs to run continiously, forever. Is there a way to deploy this in Azure in anything else than a Virtual Machine without causing a signigficant increase in complexity and management?

I have read about function apps, durable functions, app service etc. However, my code is not a web-app, it takes around 4 hours to run once and needs to run in a loop. Based on the information about these they aren't supposed to be used for a job like this. Is there any other alternative in Azure?

Comment: You can also try to check Azure Batch service to run your Python Script that calls DB and file, If you have pulled your python image from docker to ACI, Check the port mappings while creating ACI is matching the port your Python app is using for the output to reflect in the ACI. Refer here :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-python

Comment: Sure, Did you refer this document -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-portal > Here> Use your python app image from your Azure container registry in the ACI and then in the networking tab instead of Port 80 as per the document, Use the port your python app is running on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use synapse analytics for scheduling. In synapse you can create notebook file to call your function and write through the ODBC connection. It is not the best practice, but it can help you with the problem. Also, you can work in the Azure Machine Learning Studio.